# Temp fileupload using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a form with an attachment, using Paperclip.

If the model is invalid when the form is submitted then I want to save a temporary copy of the file, so the user doesn't have to re-upload the file after they fix the form submission.

What I'm doing now is to use regular Ruby file operations to save the file.. but this is pretty low level compared to using Paperclip.

What might work best to allow me to save a temp Paperclip attachment that will then allow me to move the temp file to my final object upon successful validation?

I'm thinking about a simple ActiveRecord object (ie., TempAttachment) where I can assign the uploaded file and then move it to the final object when the object saves successfully.

Does that make sense?  Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: You're still going to have to do something hacky that way though, as you can't store the file locally in the Rails app or db - you have to use a service like AWS S3.

Comment: @AlexLynham: Why can't this be stored in the app (under /public or custom dir)?

Comment: Ah, actually I think my point only applies to Heroku because of the way they handle your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do this as you proposed. But while you're saving a temporary attachment object to keep track of this file... why not make your life a bit easier and just save the model itself flagged as 'incomplete'?

You can set an incomplete model to bypass many of your validations, while blocking out incomplete models from areas that should not be using them.

However, guaranteeing that you don't mix an 'incomplete' model with valid ones may get a bit complicated.  Depending on the complexity of your application, this may not be a great idea - in which case I would recommend sticking with your initial plan.

Comment: I completed this last night with tempObjects.. however, after reading yours, I think I could use the unvalidated object in the same way.  I just have an unsaved object in session that can be used to display the file which was submitted on the last post.